# How to log users activity in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, logging

Very simple question I'm not able to find a good answer for...

I have a lot of Entities in my Symfony 2.6 - when ever a user makes some changes to any one of them I would like to have a log entry with who/what/where.

Who maked the changes. (user id)
What did he/she do. ( POST/PUT data)
Where was this done (which entity / url)

[EDIT]

It could perhaps just be a table with these columns:

- userid
- data
- entity
- created

[/EDIT]

Is there a bundle for this?

Comment: I use Monolog for this

Answer (score 2):

For my projects I usually use the [EntityAudit bundle](https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit). What it does is save a copy of the old state whenever an audited entity is changed. By comparing those to the current version you can see what has changed.

It also gives you a revision history that lists all the entities that have changed in your database.

Comment: Entity Audit is almost everything I need - but the many to many isn't covered here. :-(

Answer (score 2):

You have several Bundles out there that do this, a couple of which have already been mentioned. I've had a lot of success with Gedmo Doctrine Extensions.

Some Documentation here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/common_extensions.html

And installation instructions here:
https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/symfony2.md

The installation is the tough part. Once that's done, all you need to do is annotate any entity fields you wish to log.